# Install application inside docker container , only when it has not been installed before?

Tags: installation, docker, containers, conditional

Is there a way to install any application inside docker container , only when it has not been installed before?

For example;

```
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
```

Will install nginx everytime on a new rebuild.
How would one check if nginx already exists? If not install else just update or do nothing. Is this possible somehow?
I have good reasons to need nginx inside another container for now getting things up and running lateron could move to seperating nginx to own container.

Comment: That's already how `apt-get` functions. If the package is already installed, it will try to upgrade it or it will do nothing.

Comment: totally overlooked that jordanm since im not using ubuntu normally but centos

Comment: `yum` functions the same way.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Docker will save each your build step. So, whenever you re-build your image, Docker will check the its cache and use the cache if you do same thing in the same state.

As @jordanm said, `yum` and `apt-get` also will check the app already installed or not. So, if you do `yum install nginx` twice, it will not re-install the nginx (as long as you don't tell the `yum` or `apt-get` to reinstall nginx).